# How to use blocks properly?

Tags: ruby

I'm very new to Ruby, so please bear with me.

Why is it a syntax error to have "test" {|s| print s}? How about "test" do |s| print s end?

Thanks

Comment: For future reference, it's usually a good idea to include the error message given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't say this:

```
"test" { |s| print s }
```

because `"test"` is a string literal, not a method. The same would apply to your `do/end` version. You could say:

```
["test"].each { |s| print s }
```

though because Arrays are Enumerable and Enumerable has an `each` method.

Answer (score 3):

The {} are usually used for one liners.

do/end for multiple lines.

But there is no rule, do what you prefer.

Notice:

If ever you need to pass several instructions in a one liner, separate them with ;

Comment: Kept my answer, remains useful for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

A block is just a chunk of code enclosed in braces or keywords do/end. As mentioned already, you typically use braces for one liners, and do/end for multiple lines of code. Blocks can appear only immediately after the calling of some method. You can think of a block as an anonymous method (one that doesn't have a method name).

In your code, you were placing a block immediately after a string literal, not a method invocation. Blocks can be used for looping, as such:

```
2.times { puts "hello" } # => 2
# >> hello
# >> hello
```

In the above code, times is a method that belongs to all integers (that is to say, it is a instance method of the Integer class). The times method executes the code in the block twice, and returns the object (2 in this case) you called it on. You can pass a block to any method, although methods that are not expecting them will simply ignore the block.

Blocks can take parameters. The parameters are placed between pipes (the '|' character). It turns out, the first example could have accepted a parameter as seen here:

```
2.times { |i| puts i.to_s + " hello" } # => 2
# >> 0 hello
# >> 1 hello
```

I've only just scratched the surface of the power of blocks. You can read more about blocks for free in the online version of [Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/intro.html#S6) (aka PickAx Book). It is a couple editions old now, but for an introduction to Ruby, you should find it sufficient. Once you understand blocks, you can start using power features of Enumerable which is included in Arrays and Hashes.